# Можно ли как то программно заставить роутер переподключиться?

Tags: сеть, router

Можно ли как-то программно заставить роутер переподключиться?

WAN-соединение (динамический ip-адрес). хочу иметь возможность, запустив скрипт, получить от провайдера новый ip-адрес. хотелось бы увидеть код на любом языке.

Comment: Универсально для любого существующего в мире маршрутизатора - нет нельзя. Всё зависит от конкретной модели и установленного ней ПО.

Comment: А чем вас прокси не устраивают? Меняйте ip сколько влезет, и не надо роутер мучать. На любом языке можно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно сделать разными способами.

1. Через HTTP. Отловите запросы, которые делает ваш браузер когда вы заставляете роутер получить новый IP вручную - и воспроизведите их в скрипте. Желательны знания протокола HTTP.
   Отловить эти запросы можно через инструменты разработчика в браузере или через [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).
2. Через telnet или ssh. Подключитесь к роутеру по этим протоколам и попробуйте найти нужную команду. В скрипте достаточно послать ее еще раз. Обычно скрипты для такого способа выходят проще - но поиск решения сложнее из-за отсутствия документации. Желательны знания UNIX.
   Для подключения можно воспользоваться [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
3. Через UPnP. Винда же как-то умеет интернет отцеплять и подцеплять обратно - значит, и для вас способ должен быть. Но тут подробностей я вообще не знаю. Нужны знания UPnP, которых у меня нет.

Более конкретных советов дать не могу: разные роутеры очень сильно отличаются друг от друга, единых стандартов нет (кроме UPnP). Даже одна и та же модель роутера, выпущенная в разные годы, может работать по-разному.

---

Предоставляет ли провайдер VPN-доступ? Если да, то можно отказаться от интернета по DHCP, подключить себе VPN - а переподключать VPN скриптом куда проще.

Еще один альтернативный вариант - [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/). Видимый IP-адрес будет меняться при каждой смене выходной ноды. Возможно, клиент можно и как-нибудь пнуть для принудительного изменения выходной ноды (перезапуск клиента - универсальный способ). Для использования этого варианта понадобится научиться работать через прокси-сервер.

Answer (score 0):

если в маршрутизаторе установлен дистрибутив [*openwrt*](https://openwrt.org/), то перезапуск всех сетевых подключений выполняется довольно стандартным для *sysvinit* способом:

```
# /etc/init.d/network restart
```